How to Unfocus a Button in Blazor/C# When Pressing the Escape Key Without Using JavaScript?
I'm currently developing a tooltip component in the Blazor framework. The functionality I'm trying to achieve is for the tooltip to disappear when the escape key is pressed while the button is focused.
I've managed to implement this functionality with the following code, but it relies on JavaScript, which I'd prefer to avoid if possible.
Here's my current implementation
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button @onclick="ToggleTooltip">test</button>
<div role="tooltip" @ref="tooltip" tabindex="0" @onkeydown="CloseTooltip">
  Password Rules:
</div>
<p>test</p>

@code {
  ElementReference tooltip;
  bool showTooltip = false;

  void ToggleTooltip()
  {
    showTooltip = !showTooltip;
    if (showTooltip)
    {
      tooltip.FocusAsync();
    }
  }

  async Task CloseTooltip(KeyboardEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Key == "Escape")
    {
      showTooltip = false;
      await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Blurred", tooltip);
      await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
  }
}

<script>
  window.Blurred = function(element) {
  element.blur();
};
</script>

<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  [role="tooltip"] {
    margin-top: .75rem;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }

  [role="tooltip"]:before {
    margin-top: -7px;
    content: "";
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-top-width: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }

  button:hover + [role="tooltip"],
  button:focus + [role="tooltip"],
  [role="tooltip"]:focus {
    display: block;
  }
</style>


In my humble opinion, when using components, it's better to control the rendering conditions of your elements using the components' flags/booleans instead of CSS pseudo-classes like hover/focus.
So I would recommend this approach:
@page "/"

<button @onclick="ToggleTooltip" @onmouseover="ShowTooltip" @onmouseout="HideTooltip">test</button>

@if (stickyTooltip || showTooltip)
{
    <div role="tooltip" @ref="tooltip" tabindex="0" @onkeydown="CloseTooltip">
    Password Rules:
    </div>
}

<p>test</p>

@code {
    
  private bool showTooltip = false;
  private bool stickyTooltip = false;

  ElementReference tooltip;

  private async Task ToggleTooltip()
  {
    stickyTooltip = !stickyTooltip;

    if (stickyTooltip)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        await Task.Delay(1); // Allow it to re-render
        
        try
        {
            await tooltip.FocusAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception){}
    }
  }

  private async Task ShowTooltip()
  {
    showTooltip = true;

    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    await Task.Delay(1); // Allow it to re-render

    try
    {
        await tooltip.FocusAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception){}
  }

  private void HideTooltip()
  {
    showTooltip = false;
  }

  private void CloseTooltip(KeyboardEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Key == "Escape")
    {
      showTooltip = false;
      stickyTooltip = false;
    }
  }
}

<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  [role="tooltip"] {
    margin-top: .75rem;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }

  [role="tooltip"]:before {
    margin-top: -7px;
    content: "";
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-top-width: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

It seems to behave as you intended, but there are still some caveats. For example, the Escape key press will only work if the tooltip has focus. If you stick the tooltip and click elsewhere, the Escape key won't trigger the tooltip's keydown event.
